# Non-audio focused applications acquire poor microphone input

Tags: windows-10, usb, audio, microphone, recording

I have an USB headset (Plantronics Rig 500 HD) with a microphone on Windows 10. The microphone can only be configured for 2-channel (stereo) sampling in Windows sound controls. When I use programs like TeamSpeak, Discord, or Audacity the audio is clear and understandable. When using non-primary-audio programs, like computer games, I have been told that the audio is distorted, and that my voice sound "demon-like".

If I go into Audacity and change the recording mode to mono, the recording does indeed become distorted in such a manner.

My hypothesis is that some programs somehow simply acquire a mono input from the microphone (which is distorted) rather than the correct stereo input.

I already use Equalizer APO with Reafir plugin to increase my mic volume (USB headsets microphone are notorious for low mic volume), and to eliminate noise. I have tried disabling Equalizer APO but that changes nothing. I tried adding the two stereo channels to L and eliminating R to get mono on L; however, the result is distorted. Each individual stereo channel L, R seems "complete" and clear by itself though.

How do I get non-distorted microphone recording for all applications?

Comment: Pure guess: You're set to 48kHz. Switch to 44.1

Comment: Going between 48kHz and 44.1 changes nothing, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I found a "solution" / workaround. But it requires two other applications: Virtual Audio Cable and Voicemeeter. My approach is that:

- Voicemeeter takes input from the microphone and forwards it in mono-mode to one of the virtual cables. The resulting mono is not distorted.
- Set the virtual cable to the default microphone / communications device so applications that is not audio-focused pick up the mono source instead.